# How to find the top any % of a dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, filter, percentile

I want to find the top 1% in my dataframe and append all the values in a list. Then i can check the first value inside and use it as a filter in the dataframe, any idea how to do it ? Or if you have a simplier way to do it !

You can find the dataframe i use here :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srptwice/forstack/main/resultat_projet.csv

What i tried is to watch my dataframe with heatmap (from Seaborn) and use a filter like that :

```
df4 = df2[df2 > 50700]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.<column name>.quantile(<percentile>)` to get the top % of a dataframe. For example, the code below would get you the rows for `df2` where `bfly` column is at the top 10% (90th percentile)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./resultstat_projet.csv')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '') # remove blank spaces in columns
df2 = df[df.bfly > df.bfly.quantile(0.9)]
print(df2)
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine, i searched for hours but with "percent" keyword and not quantile, thanks a lot